# Difference Between QuickGraph from CodePlex and CodeProject

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, graphviz, quickgraph

I'm wanting to use QuickGraph to draw some graphs in C# using GraphViz. I've had a look at the libraries available from [CodePlex](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) and [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/quickgraph.aspx). They appear to be quite different.
What are the major differences between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The article and the project are from the same person. The project at CodePlex is being maintained, so I think you should try this. The Code Project article seems to be the first edition of a library, that later evolved to an open source project.

Comment: This is correct; the CodePlex version is being maintained by Peli (who also created Pex/Moles) and takes contributions from other Microsoft devs, including myself